# Using Filtered results to create a flag Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I have a data source that has Students and their marks for 3 subjects.

In the first sheet I want to filter on a few students, and in the second sheet I want to filter on couple of other students.

In the third sheet, I want to show only the results of the filters in the first 2 sheets.

I was wondering if I could add a new field with a flag that I can make '1', based on what is selected, and filter for '1' in the third sheet.

Let me know if this is possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What you're describing sound a lot like a Set in Tableau

You'd create a set based off the student (names?) field for your first two worksheets

You can then create a Calc Field that has the logic IF SET 1 = TRUE OR SET 2 = TRUE THEN Student END

Then Filter your third worksheet on the calculated field

Comment: Or even simpler, instead of creating the calculated field, select both sets, right click and create a combined set that is the union of the two. Then just drop the combined set on the filter shelf